# EF CORE Select distinct grandchildren with many-to-may relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq, model, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to learn EF Core and hit this wall since I'm also fairly new to LINQ

Consider the model:
[image]

I'm trying to get all the distinct users from a single company;

The SQL statement would be something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT gau.AppUserId, au.Name, au.Id FROM Companies c 
INNER JOIN Groups g ON g.CompanyId = c.Id
INNER JOIN GroupAppUsers gau ON gau.GroupId = g.Id
INNER JOIN AppUsers au ON gau.AppUserId = au.Id
Where c.Id = 40
```

Result:
[image]

How would I build this query like this? (Without the includes)

```
            return await context.Companies
            .Include(g => g.Groups)
                .ThenInclude(au => au.AppUsers)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.AppUser)
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
```

*Also, I'm not sure about the DB Model, I'm trying to avoid circular references but I think I should put Users linked with Companies instead of Groups, what do you think??

Comment: Why without the includes? Couldn't you just add `.Select(c => c.Groups.AppUsers.AppUser).Distinct()`?

Comment: @NetMage Without the includes to return a simple AppUser object.
Also, I didn't understand your suggestion, would you mind to explain a little further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm trying to get all the distinct users from a single company

Rather than starting from companies and navigating to users, thus multiplying the users due to many-to-many relationship and then applying `Disctinct` operator, you could simply start from users and apply `Any` based criteria, thus eliminating the need of `Disctinct` at all.

Something like this (the `DbSet` / navigation property names could be different):

```
var companyUsers = await context.Users
    .Where(u => u.UserGroups.Any(ug => ug.Group.Company.Id == id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: It does seem easier and faster to do this way! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your linking table (GroupAppUser) isn't modeled as an entity, something like:

```
var q = from c in db.Companies
        from g in c.Groups
        from u in g.AppUsers
        select u;
```

or in Lambda form:

```
var q = db.Companies
          .SelectMany(c => c.Groups)
          .SelectMany(g => g.AppUsers);
```

Comment: I think you need `.Distinct()`?

Comment: Yep, Probably so.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the single `Companies` object, you can use the Navigation properties to get the `AppUser` objects:

```
return await context.Companies
                    .Include(g => g.Groups)
                    .ThenInclude(au => au.AppUsers)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.AppUser)
                    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id)
                    .Groups.AppUsers.Distinct();
```